# How to recursively upload a directory which has directories and files to a server through HTTPS using curl command?

Tags: command-line, bash, https, curl, post

This is the command I am using:

```
curl --insecure -i https://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/project/conatinername/foldertobeuploaded/${file}.html -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/html charset=UTF-8; -H "Content-Length:0" -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -T /home/folder/${file}.html
```

I want to upload a whole directory to my Object Service hosted. 
Also, I want to give a switch case which will help me upload every file according to the content type.

Here is the sh file

```
for file in /home/folder/*
 if [ ${extension} == "html" ];
  do
        curl --insecure https://10.147.202.80:8081/swift/v1/JFSTechBackup/${file} -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/html charset=UTF-8; -H "Content-Length:0" -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -T /home/folder/${file}

 elif [ ${extension} == "css" ]; then
   do
         curl --insecure https:/home/folder/${file} -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/css -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -T /home/folder/${file}
 else if [ ${extension} == "png" ]; then
   do
        curl --insecure https:/home/folder/${file} -X PUT -H "Content-Type: image/png -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -T /home/folder/${file}

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to attempt re-writing your script, but to recursively find all files you could use `find`, for example to find all regular files

```
find directory -type f
```

or to find everything that's not a directory

```
find directory \! -type d
```

Then you could run some command on each item, `xargs` would be great (with null-separated names here)

```
find directory \! -type d -print0 | xargs -0 curl ...
```

If you wanted the filename extension examining & processing, then you could use a separate `find` for each `-name *.extension` type, or use something like a while read loop

```
find directory \! -type d | while read onthisfile; do echo Processing "$onthisfile; done
```